# insert Into and Union of Tables

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I'm using MS-Access. I have a table A looks like :

```
 id isin    typ1    typ2                                                                                 
  1 aa      typA    typB                                                                                 
 2  bb      typD    typC
```

I need to insert into a table B that looks like:

```
id  isin    fld     value                                                                                
 1   aa     typ1    typA                                                                                 
 2   aa     typ2    typB                                                                                 
 3   bb     typ1    typD                                                                                 
 4   bb     typ2    typC
```

Can I do it with an SQL instruction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `id` field in table B is an Autonumber and ordering of the values is important, then you can use

```
insert into B (isin, fld, [value])
SELECT isin, fld, [value] from
  (select isin, "typ1" as fld, typ1 as [value] from A
  union all
  select isin, "typ2" as fld, typ2 from A) as R
order by isin, fld
```

keep in mind that the `value` field name is a reserved keyword in MS Access.

Comment: please see here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
insert into b (id, isin, fld, value)
    select id, isin, fld, typ2
    from a
    union all
    select id + 2, isin, fld,
           switch(id = 1, "typD", id = 2, "typC")
    from a;
```